# Add new checkout option with iframe below it in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I am trying to add another WooCommerce payment method called **Piraeus Bank Gateway** on checkout page and when selected, this payment method will load an iframe like below (the iframe will redirect to the banks site *lets call it `$url`*).

How can I declare the content that will be displayed below the Checkout option?

Image of what I need to do: 
[image: Image of what I need to do]

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php

/*
  Plugin Name: pireaus_getaway
  Plugin URI: 
  Description: 
  Version: 1.0.0
  Author: 
  Author URI: 
  License: N/W
  License URI: 
*/

/*check if plugin runs inside wordpress if not exit*/
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) 
    exit;

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'initialise', 0);

function initialise(){
    if (!class_exists('WC_Payment_Gateway'))
        return;  /*check if Wordpress WooCommerce Payment Exists if Not Exit*/

    load_plugin_textdomain('pireaus_getaway', false, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)) . '/languages/');  /*Load the .MO files with the translations*/


    /* DEFINE GETAWAY CLASS */
    class WC_Piraeusbank_Gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
        public function __construct() {
            global $woocommerce;

            /*================================================== Initialise the WC_Payment_Gateway with Values (USEFULL ONLY FOR WORDPRESS IDE) ========================================================================= */
            $this->id = 'piraeusbank_gateway';
            $this->icon = apply_filters('piraeusbank_icon', plugins_url('assets/PB_blue_GR.png', __FILE__));
            $this->has_fields = false;
            $this->notify_url = WC()->api_request_url('WC_Piraeusbank_Gateway');
            $this->method_description = __('Piraeus bank Payment Gateway allows you to accept payment through various channels such as Maestro, Mastercard, AMex cards, Diners  and Visa cards On your Woocommerce Powered Site.', 'pireaus_getaway');
            $this->redirect_page_id = $this->get_option('redirect_page_id');
            $this->method_title = 'Piraeus bank  Gateway';
            // Load the form fields.
            $this->init_form_fields();
            /*============================================================================================================================================================================================================ */



            /*================================================== Create transaction Table =================================================================================================================================*/
            global $wpdb; // create query later for table creation
            if ($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . $wpdb->prefix . "piraeusbank_transactions'") === $wpdb->prefix . 'piraeusbank_transactions') {
                // The database table exist
            } else {
                // Table does not exist
                $query = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'piraeusbank_transactions (id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, merch_ref varchar(50) not null, trans_ticket varchar(32) not null , timestamp datetime default null, PRIMARY KEY (id))';
                $wpdb->query($query);
            }
            // Load the settings.
            $this->init_settings();
            /*============================================================================================================================================================================================================ */

            /* get_option == A safe way of getting values for a named option from the options database table. If the desired option does not exist, or no value is associated with it, FALSE will be returned.] */
            // Define user set variables for Setting Of Woocommerce Piraeus GETAWAY in Admin Panel
            $this->title = $this->get_option('title');
            $this->description = $this->get_option('description');
            $this->pb_PayMerchantId = $this->get_option('pb_PayMerchantId');
            $this->pb_AcquirerId = $this->get_option('pb_AcquirerId');
            $this->pb_PosId = $this->get_option('pb_PosId');
            $this->pb_Username = $this->get_option('pb_Username');
            $this->pb_Password = $this->get_option('pb_Password');
            $this->pb_authorize = $this->get_option('pb_authorize');
            $this->pb_installments = $this->get_option('pb_installments');
            //Actions
            add_action('woocommerce_receipt_piraeusbank_gateway', array($this, 'receipt_page')); //receipt_page($order_id) == > returns receipt page for the order
            add_action('woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array($this, 'process_admin_options')); // process_admin_options() == > Admin Panel Options Processing – Saves the options to the DB
            // Payment listener/API hook
            add_action('woocommerce_api_wc_piraeusbank_gateway', array($this, 'check_piraeusbank_response'));
        }  //end of construct !


        //========================================================CREATE THE HTML OF THE SETTING PAGE OF ADMIN PANEL (Contains Fuctions USED ONLY FOR ADMIN PANEL FORMATION) ============================================
        public function admin_options() {
                echo '<h3>' . __('Piraeus Bank Gateway', 'pireaus_getaway') . '</h3>';
                echo '<p>' . __('Piraeus Bank Gateway allows you to accept payment through various channels such as Maestro, Mastercard, AMex cards, Diners  and Visa cards.', 'pireaus_getaway') . '</p>';


                echo '<table class="form-table">';
                $this->generate_settings_html();
                echo '</table>';
        }
            // init_form_fields() ==> Create the Admin Panel form specifying the datatypes 
            //The WooCommerce settings API is used by shipping methods and payment gateways to display, save and load options.
        function init_form_fields() {       
                $this->form_fields = array(
                    'enabled' => array(
                        'title' => __('Enable/Disable', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'type' => 'checkbox',
                        'label' => __('Enable Piraeus Bank Gateway', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'description' => __('Enable or disable the gateway.', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'desc_tip' => true,
                        'default' => 'yes'
                    ),
                    'title' => array(
                        'title' => __('Title', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'description' => __('This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'desc_tip' => false,
                        'default' => __('Piraeus Bank Gateway', 'pireaus_getaway')
                    ),
                    'description' => array(
                        'title' => __('Description', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'type' => 'textarea',
                        'description' => __('This controls the description which the user sees during checkout.', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'default' => __('Pay Via Piraeus Bank: Accepts  Mastercard, Visa cards and etc.', 'pireaus_getaway')
                    ),
                    'pb_PayMerchantId' => array(
                        'title' => __('Piraeus Bank Merchant ID', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'description' => __('Enter Your Piraeus Bank Merchant ID', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'default' => '',
                        'desc_tip' => true
                    ),
                    'pb_AcquirerId' => array(
                        'title' => __('Piraeus Bank Acquirer ID', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'description' => __('Enter Your Piraeus Bank Acquirer ID', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'default' => '',
                        'desc_tip' => true
                    ),
                    'pb_PosId' => array(
                        'title' => __('Piraeus Bank POS ID', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'description' => __('Enter your Piraeus Bank POS ID', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'default' => '',
                        'desc_tip' => true
                    ), 'pb_Username' => array(
                        'title' => __('Piraeus Bank Username', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'description' => __('Enter your Piraeus Bank Username', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'default' => '',
                        'desc_tip' => true
                    ), 'pb_Password' => array(
                        'title' => __('Piraeus Bank Password', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'description' => __('Enter your Piraeus Bank Password', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'default' => '',
                        'desc_tip' => true
                    ), 'pb_authorize' => array(
                        'title' => __('Pre-Authorize', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'type' => 'checkbox',
                        'label' => __('Enable to capture preauthorized payments', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'default' => 'yes',
                        'description' => __('Default payment method is Purchase, enable for Pre-Authorized payments. You will then need to accept them from Peiraeus Bank AdminTool', 'pireaus_getaway')
                    ),
                    'redirect_page_id' => array(
                        'title' => __('Return Page', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'type' => 'select',
                        'options' => $this->pb_get_pages('Select Page'),
                        'description' => __('URL of success page', 'pireaus_getaway')
                    ),
                    'pb_installments' => array(
                        'title' => __('Max Installments', 'pireaus_getaway'),
                        'type' => 'select',
                        'options' => $this->pb_get_installments('Select Installments'),
                        'description' => __('1 to 24 Installments,1 for one time payment. You must contact Peiraeus Bank first', 'pireaus_getaway')
                    )
                );
        }


        function pb_get_pages($title = false, $indent = true) {
                $wp_pages = get_pages('sort_column=menu_order');
                $page_list = array();
                if ($title)
                    $page_list[] = $title;
                foreach ($wp_pages as $page) {
                    $prefix = '';
                    // show indented child pages?
                    if ($indent) {
                        $has_parent = $page->post_parent;
                        while ($has_parent) {
                            $prefix .= ' - ';
                            $next_page = get_page($has_parent);
                            $has_parent = $next_page->post_parent;
                        }
                    }
                    // add to page list array array
                    $page_list[$page->ID] = $prefix . $page->post_title;
                }
                $page_list[-1] = __('Thank you page', 'pireaus_getaway');
                return $page_list;
        }


        function pb_get_installments($title = false, $indent = true) {      
                for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++) {
                    $installment_list[$i] = $i;
                }
                return $installment_list;
        }
    /*============================================================================================================================================================================================================ */



    //===========================================================================ACTUAL CODE ======================================================================================================================

    function generate_piraeusbank_form($order_id) {
        global $woocommerce;
        global $wpdb;

        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        //echo $this->pb_authorize;

        if ($this->pb_authorize == "yes") {
            $requestType = '00';
            $ExpirePreauth = '30';
        } else {
            $requestType = '02';
            $ExpirePreauth = '0';
        }
        $installments = 1;
        try {
            $soap = new SoapClient(url1);
            $ticketRequest = array(
                'Username' => $this->pb_Username,
                'Password' => hash('md5', $this->pb_Password),
                'MerchantId' => $this->pb_PayMerchantId,
                'PosId' => $this->pb_PosId,
                'AcquirerId' => $this->pb_AcquirerId,
                'MerchantReference' => $order_id,
                'RequestType' => $requestType,
                'ExpirePreauth' => $ExpirePreauth,
                'Amount' => $order->get_total(),
                'CurrencyCode' => '978',
                'Installments' => $installments,
                'Bnpl' => '0',
                'Parameters' => ''
            );
            $xml = array(
                'Request' => $ticketRequest
            );
            $oResult = $soap->IssueNewTicket($xml);
            if ($oResult->IssueNewTicketResult->ResultCode == 0) {
                // store TranTicket in table    
                $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix . 'piraeusbank_transactions', array('trans_ticket' => $oResult->IssueNewTicketResult->TranTicket, 'merch_ref' => $order_id, 'timestamp' => current_time('mysql', 1)));
                $LanCode = "el-GR";
                return 
                    '<form action="' . esc_url(url) . '" method="post" id="pb_payment_form" target="output_frame">              
                        <input type="hidden" id="AcquirerId" name="AcquirerId" value="' . esc_attr($this->pb_AcquirerId) . '"/>
                        <input type="hidden" id="MerchantId" name="MerchantId" value="' . esc_attr($this->pb_PayMerchantId) . '"/>
                        <input type="hidden" id="PosID" name="PosID" value="' . esc_attr($this->pb_PosId) . '"/>
                        <input type="hidden" id="User" name="User" value="' . esc_attr($this->pb_Username) . '"/>
                        <input type="hidden" id="LanguageCode"  name="LanguageCode" value="' . $LanCode . '"/>
                        <input type="hidden" id="MerchantReference" name="MerchantReference"  value="' . esc_attr($order_id) . '"/>
                    <!-- Button Fallback -->
                    <div class="payment_buttons">
                        <input type="submit" class="button alt" id="submit_pb_payment_form" value="' . __('Pay via Pireaus Bank', 'pireaus_getaway') . '" /> <a class="button cancel" href="' . esc_url($order->get_cancel_order_url()) . '">' . __('Cancel order &amp; restore cart', 'pireaus_getaway') . '</a>

                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(".payment_buttons").hide();
                    </script>
                </form>
                <iframe name="output_frame" width="800px" height="455"></iframe>
                ';
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo __('An error occured, please contact the Administrator', 'pireaus_getaway');
                echo ('Result code is '.$oResult->IssueNewTicketResult->ResultCode);
            }
        } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
            $order->add_order_note(__('Error' . $fault, ''));
            echo __('Error' . $fault, '');
        }
    }


     function process_payment($order_id) {

        /*
          get_permalink was used instead of $order->get_checkout_payment_url in redirect in order to have a fixed checkout page to provide to Piraeus Bank
         */

        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        return array(
            'result' => 'success',
            'redirect' => add_query_arg('order', $order->id, add_query_arg('key', $order->order_key, get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('pay'))))
        );
    }

    /**
     * Output for the order received page.
     * */
    function receipt_page($order) {
        echo '<p>' . __('Thank you - your order is now pending payment. You should be automatically redirected to Peiraeus Paycenter to make payment.', 'pireaus_getaway') . '</p>';
        echo $this->generate_piraeusbank_form($order);
    }

   /*============================================================================================================================================================================================================ */

}// END OF  class WordCommerce_Pireaus_Gateway

    //===========================================================================ADD PLUGIN TO ADMIN PANEL ========================================================================================================
    function piraeusbank_message() {
        $order_id = absint(get_query_var('order-received'));
        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        $payment_method = $order->payment_method;

        if (is_order_received_page() && ( 'piraeusbank_gateway' == $payment_method )) {

            $piraeusbank_message = get_post_meta($order_id, '_piraeusbank_message', true);
             if (!empty($piraeusbank_message)) {
            $message = $piraeusbank_message['message'];
            $message_type = $piraeusbank_message['message_type'];

            delete_post_meta($order_id, '_piraeusbank_message');


                wc_add_notice($message, $message_type);
            }
        }
    }

    add_action('wp', 'piraeusbank_message');

    function woocommerce_add_piraeusbank_gateway($methods) {
        $methods[] = 'WC_Piraeusbank_Gateway';
        return $methods;
    }

    add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'woocommerce_add_piraeusbank_gateway');



    if (version_compare(WOOCOMMERCE_VERSION, "2.1") <= 0) {
        add_filter('plugin_action_links', 'piraeusbank_plugin_action_links', 10, 2);
        function piraeusbank_plugin_action_links($links, $file) {
            static $this_plugin;
            if (!$this_plugin) {
                $this_plugin = plugin_basename(__FILE__);
            }
            if ($file == $this_plugin) {
                $settings_link = '<a href="' . get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=woocommerce_settings&tab=payment_gateways&section=WC_piraeusbank_Gateway">Settings</a>';
                array_unshift($links, $settings_link);
            }
            return $links;
        }
    }
    else {
        add_filter('plugin_action_links', 'piraeusbank_plugin_action_links', 10, 2);
        function piraeusbank_plugin_action_links($links, $file) {
            static $this_plugin;
            if (!$this_plugin) {
                $this_plugin = plugin_basename(__FILE__);
            }
            if ($file == $this_plugin) {
                $settings_link = '<a href="' . get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=checkout&section=WC_Piraeusbank_Gateway">Settings</a>';
                array_unshift($links, $settings_link);
            }
            return $links;
        }
    }
    //===================================================================================================================================================================================================================
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Kindly, but what you are trying to do is insecure.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec how would you do it then ?

Comment: The normal behavior: 1 WC checkout / 2 Bank Payment gateway / 3 WC Thankyou…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thank you :)